# gerrit-trigger not notifying gerrit when rest api is enabled

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

when using the gerrit-trigger plugin with REST-API disabled everything works as expected

after enabling the REST-API however it seems like gerrit-trigger is not even trying to set the verify label like he used to

- when testing the rest connection in the gerrit-trigger-config it succeeds and i see the request in gerrits httpd_log
- after a job completed that should report verified status to gerrit there is no request by jenkins in gerrits httpd_log
- with rest api disabled i see something like "INFO: Notifying BuildCompleted to gerrit: ..." in jenkins log
- with rest api enabled nothing in jenkins log about notifying gerrit
- gerrit 2.14.4 - jenkins 2.73.3 - gerrit-trigger 2.26.2

so when enabling the REST-API it becomes unusable for me because the verified label does not get reported back to gerrit.

can anyone help me sort this issue out? i need to enable REST for some other plugin to work (disabled atm so not the cause of failure)

Comment: Just some checks: Is your label in Gerrit named "Verified" exactly? Or it's called "Verification" or something else? Have you "Enabled Verified" in the gerrit-trigger config?

Comment: the label is called exactly "Verified", the "Enable Verified" checkbox is checked, in fact i can not even uncheck it, if i do uncheck and save, the box is checked again after a reload, while "Enable Code-Review" can stay unchecked

Comment: Weird... I was able to uncheck (Gerrit-Trigger 2.26.2 too). I was not able to use the Verified with REST too but, in my case, the Gerrit label is named "Verification" :-( using the SSH command is possible to describe the correct command but using REST I can't change "Verified" to "Verification" so I don't know if it didn't work because of the name or it didn't work because of a bug or a mis-configuration.